# Start and End Timestamp with Username

Tags: vba, timestamp

I have the code below, which will be dependent on triggers, column A and B, to indicate timestamps for each completed entry, however, i keep on getting a runtime error 1004 pop-up:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A2:B501")) Is Nothing Then
Target.Offset(0, 12) = Now
Target.Offset(1, 13) = Now
Target.Offset(0, 14) = Environ("UserName")

End If
End Sub
```

I'm new to doing VBA, hopefully you guys can help me.

Comment: The code works fine here, which line is the error being raised from?

Comment: Well, "fine"... I mean I don't get a repro on your 1004. Seems awkward that editing column A would put the username in column O, and editing column B puts the username in column P ...but that's what your code is doing anyway, and it works.

Answer (score 1):

Better way to handle this is something like:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim rng As Range

    Set rng = Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A2:B501"))
    'Work with "rng", not "Target", since Target might contain cells
    '   outside of ColA or B...
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        'Target (and so rng) could contain multiple cells
        '   so need to address them individually
        For Each c In rng.Cells
            'EDIT:
            c.Offset(0, 12) = Now 'ColA >> M, ColB >> N
            c.EntireRow.Cells(1, "O") = Environ("UserName")
        Next c

    End If

End Sub
```

However since you're handling both ColA and ColB there's a chance you may end up overwriting values since the ranges offset from A and B will overlap

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks! My purpose is to have a start and end time on the file, so in column A, they will just put any entry and it will trigger a start timestamp in Column M at the same time put the username in Column O, and then after they're done filling up other columns, the end timestamp will be triggered by an entry in column B.

Comment: See my edits.  Still unclear exactly where everything is supposed to go.  Why the row offset for example?

Comment: your edits are perfect. thank you for all the help Tim! im just new in this vba stuff. and im learning by test and try.